# Streamlit don't show progress bar in cache_data function

Tags: caching, progress-bar, streamlit

With streamlit, I am setting a heavy function to `cache_data` type to avoid recalculation. Since the function is time consuming, I also want to create a progress bar inside it. However, I find the it cannot work with `cache_data` specified.

The following is a MWE

```py
import streamlit as st
from time import sleep

@st.cache_data(show_spinner = False)
def showProgressBar():
    cur = 0
    total = 100
    my_bar = st.progress(cur / total, text = "%d / %d" % (cur, total))
    while cur < total:
        sleep(0.05)
        cur = cur + 1
        my_bar.progress(cur / total, text = "%d / %d" % (cur, total))
    my_bar.empty()

### Main ###
st.set_page_config(page_title="Test Progress In Cache Function", page_icon=":bar_chart:",layout="wide")
st.title(" :bar_chart: Test")
showProgressBar()
st.text('Test Finish')
```

Turn out the bar never shows up with such code. But if I comment out the `@st.cache_data` line, the progress bar works as expected.

In [This thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/display-the-progress-bar-while-a-cached-function-is-running/6676) similar problem is mentioned about `progress` and `st.cache`, the workaround seems to be related to `suppress_st_warning = True`, however with the depreciation of `st.cache`, this parameter seems no longer available to `st.cache_data`

Anyone can provide some help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your heavy calculation is `sleep(0.05)`, here is a way to do it. This piece of code extracts the heavy calculation out of the progress bar handling making sure the `cache_data` decorator can be used only on non-Streamlit operations:

```py
import streamlit as st
from time import sleep
from random import randint

@st.cache_data(show_spinner = False)
def do_heavy_calc(n):
    print(f"First time seeing {n}")
    sleep(0.05)


def showProgressBar():
    cur = 0
    total = 100
    my_bar = st.progress(cur / total, text = "%d / %d" % (cur, total))
    while cur < total:
        n = randint(1, 100)
        # Add a random number since I suppose you don't want to run
        # the exact same function everytime(?)
        do_heavy_calc(n)
        cur = cur + 1
        my_bar.progress(cur / total, text = "%d / %d" % (cur, total))
    my_bar.empty()

### Main ###
st.set_page_config(page_title="Test Progress In Cache Function", page_icon=":bar_chart:",layout="wide")
st.title(" :bar_chart: Test")
showProgressBar()
st.text('Test Finish')
```

---

If however you wanted to keep track of one long function that you call only once, you can convert it to a generator that yields the current step at which the `do_heavy_calc` function is currently at. I don't recommend this however (it feels a bit hacky), but it seems to work fine in my tests.

Two things to note:

- `cache_data` is replaced by `cache_resource` since `cache_data` raises `streamlit.runtime.caching.cache_errors.UnserializableReturnValueError`.
- I put a underscore (`_`) in front of the 2 input arguments: this is to ensure that they will not be used for caching purposes. See this [streamlit documentation page](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching) at section "Excluding input parameters".

```py
import streamlit as st
from time import sleep

@st.cache_resource(show_spinner = False)
def do_heavy_calc(_cur, _total):
    while _cur < _total:
        # yield where you are so that the progress bar on the outside can
        # keep track
        yield _cur
        sleep(0.05)
        _cur = _cur + 1

def showProgressBar():
    min_ = 0
    max_ = 100
    my_bar = st.progress(min_ / max_, text = "%d / %d" % (min_, max_))
    for c in do_heavy_calc(0, max_):
        my_bar.progress(c / max_, text = "%d / %d" % (c, max_))
    my_bar.empty()

### Main ###
st.set_page_config(page_title="Test Progress In Cache Function", page_icon=":bar_chart:",layout="wide")
st.title(" :bar_chart: Test")
showProgressBar()
st.text('Test Finish')
```

Comment: Thanks @vvvvv . The first way works for me. The second one seems a bit tricky. Seems both of them are putting `st.progress` outside `st.cache_data` or `st.cache_resource`, so when the streamlit loop runs again, the bar will always show up but progress fast, it is enough for my case.